Request a copy of reference from previous company?
I applied for new job, I was hired and awaiting references from my two previous companies.
After month of waiting, I have been rejected by the new company based on (which I believe the previous companies gave false references), despite being assured that their reference would be good ones.
Therefore, can I request copies of these references from the present company or previous companies?

You can request the moon on a stick if you want.

"which I believe the previous companies gave false references". Do you know for sure 100%  that is true ? Are you sure you passed all the interviews with excellent scores, and no other candidates have better qualifications than you for this job ?  --- On the other hand, your profile picture of a "Samurai raising a sword" looks really cool for a video game. I would upvote that picture. :-)

Were you actually hired then fired after a month or were you told you had been selected and before your first day you were informed you were no longer going to be needed?

Yes,  I passed all three stages of interviews

In the US, most companies will typically only give employment dates. Just for this very reason. Or you sure that it wasn't some other reason? Social media posts or background check?

The only reason I can deduce is that I helped other team member's with software problems within the department. Also, helped my team manager corrected his mistakes

Note that speculation from the outside most of the time is pretty fruitless. The company might just have seen a downturn or another person took over department control and decided to not hire more people - and you were easy to get rid of, cause not even hired completely yet. Not saying one or the other is true, but I'd be very careful about drawing conclusions.  For deciding whether you legally have a right to request references in writing that would also be used for when a company asks (or a similar law) the country would probably help.

Though even if such a law exists and they want to "warn" someone about you they can always give inofficial feedback...

How can the company give "false" references? If they called the company and they gave a reference it cannot be false. Or was the janitor picking the phone and pretending to be your ex-boss?


Therefore, can I request copies of these references from the present
company or previous companies?

You can request them.
The companies are under no obligation to provide them, and I would be surprised if they did.

Is that standard procedure across the globe?

Where I am, it's completely normal to request a proof of having worked on the previous company and the company will, assuming you weren't burning bridges, usually say you were a good and competent employee. I don't see why the company will tell you what they told other companies tho

In general US, company references are usually limited to confirming dates worked and maybe job title.
References from individuals are the ones where details appear. And since you can decide who you want to give as references you have some control over what opinions are likely to be voiced.
If you aren't landing jobs, that is far more likely a matter of a tight job market or your applying to the wrong jobs or your having a bad resume or your needing to improve your interview skills than that anyone is sabotaging you. Among other things, most people don't care enough to waste time thinking of ways to make your life difficult.
The paranoids are not out to get you.

The location tag is extremely important. People do references differently in different jurisdictions.

I have been rejected by the new company based on (which I believe the previous companies gave false references)

One negative reference is enough to torpedo a job offer. What makes you think you received negative references from BOTH your former employers instead of just one bad reference?
Anyway, you need to make sure the titles and the dates you gave are the same exact ones your former employers gave out, and that the reason you gave for leaving are the same ones they gave. So at the very least, you need to contact the head of HR for each one of your former employers and let me know what happened. If someone said too much, HR probably won't admit it, but may be they can reprimand that person.
In the US, lawyers representing workers will hire the same third party services employers use to check references. This is because no former employer will give a bad reference if they think they're talking to a representative of the worker, they'll just lie.
With that said, before you contact an employment lawyer, I think it's in your interest to talk directly to your former employers (as uncomfortable as it may be), and see what you can uncover yourself.
References are a tricky business. Laws vary from country to country, and from state to state. Some times, even a positive reference with coded language can tell the person inquiring not to hire the person. And proving that someone lied can be very tricky. It's possible that may be they didn't even provide a "false reference" for this to happen.

You can request references - independent of local laws you can typically always ask. Just asking and being fine with being told "no", should be fine in most areas if you are polite. In some countries laws might help you to actually get some sort of information out of such a request, if they don't want to provide you with what you ask for.
That being said, in any case you will hardly be able to tell if they really wanted to badmouth you. In countries where you cannot write something positive, many write super positive reviews and positive reviews, meaning the "just" positive reviews can be bad reviews, but you need to read a few from the same company to actually compare. So with just a single point of data you might find it hard to appropriately judge how good a reference it is.
Even then, if they wanted to badmouth you and didn't want you to know, they can just do that "inofficially".
That might also not be due to actual decisions by the managers. It could just be some people from the old company know some people from the new company and they talked over a beer.
And very likely all of this does have nothing to do with these references. Your prospective new employer might simply changed their mind about hiring more people and it was still pretty easy to get rid of you - since you were not fully on board yet. They might have run into financial trouble or the head of department changed and decided to assign resources differently. Unless you feel you have grounds to sue (and then you should probably talk to a lawyer to figure out what proof you need and how you can acquire it), I would recommend to let this slide and focus on the next opportunity. Wasting time on trying to dig into the reasons of why it did not work out will likely not help you nor change any minds. Letting it occupy your thoughts will just distract you from moving on and finding something fitting.
